# Calling function while in insert mode that allows editing buffer

Tags: python, vim

I'm attempting to write a vim plugin using the vim python module that handles basic bracket completion (I know this exists, it's more of a learning exercise).  I've run in to an issue where I'd like to remap '(' to a function in insert mode.  C-o is an option, but when it leaves insert mode, it moves  the cursor to the left which trashes the cursor position.  As far as I can think, it's impossible to tell if the '(' was entered at pos 0 or pos 1, because either will end up with pos of 0 while in the function call.

I've tried implementing it with expr or C-r, but the issue is I'd like to control cursor position after the insert of the bracket (i.e. move to the right of the bracket) and edit the buffer (both of which aren't allowed in when using expr or C-r).

So, is there a way to either call a function in insert mode that allows editing the buffer/changing cursor position?  If not, is there a way to capture the cursor position prior to leaving insert mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wrong, `<C-R>` does allow you to edit the buffer.  Ended up using a mapping like `inoremap ( <C-R>=OpenChar('(')<cr>` where OpenChar calls the python function to do the work then returns "" to not insert anything after.